# How works PkgPredictions.db and gass.db in an android file system?

Tags: android, database, file

I am looking for information or documentation about `PkgPredictions.db` and `gass.db` files.

I found the first one in a full Android file system.
The path is: `Dump/data/system/PkgPredictions.db`

and for the second one :
The path is : `Dump/data/data/com.google.android.gms/databases/gass.db`

For PkgPredictions.db it seems to be a kind of "prefetch" as it tracks the execution of the application with timestamps.

I don't know when these file were introduced.
I already found it on Android 10 and 11.

So, if anyone has any information about the Android version when these files were introduced or an explanation, I'd be very grateful.